# Не обновляется localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, localstorage, useeffect

У меня в `localStorage` хранится массив с объектами, который я занёс далее в переменную `localUsers`

```
localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(usersObj));
const localUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
```

далее через `useEffect` при первом монтировании компонента весь массив `localUsers` назначается в стейт `[users]`

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setUsers(localUsers);
  }, []);
```

на этом этапе работает всё так, как я ожидаю: на странице отображаются пользователи.
но в моём приложении есть функция добавления нового пользователя и здесь у меня проблемы. вот функция добавления нового пользователя:

```
  function addUser({ ...user }) {
    localUsers.push(user);
    console.log(localUsers);
    setUsers(localUsers);
  }
```

я не понимаю почему, но если я уберу  `setUsers(localUsers);` из функции выше, то `console.log(localUsers);` будет сообщать о том, что `localStorage` обновляется нормально и при каждом добавлении(а равно и использовании моей функции) в `localUsers` добавляется новый объект с новым пользователем. а если я оставлю `setUsers(localUsers);`, то добавляется только один новый объект и при последующей попытке добавить нового пользователя – меняется только последний объект на новые значения, но не добавляется новый. я не понимаю как и почему это работает. я хотел бы получить объяснения почему так происходит и если вы понимаете как можно сделать, чтобы все-таки можно было добавлять пользователя через `localStorage`(мне важно именно с ним работать), то так же, пожалуйста, объяснить мне. спасибо.

**UPD полный код компонента:**

```
export default function ToDoApp() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);

  localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(usersObj));
  const localUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setUsers(localUsers);
  }, []);

  function addUser({ ...user }) {
    console.log(user);
    localUsers.push(user);
    console.log(localUsers);
    setUsers(localUsers);
  }

  const check = () => console.log(localUsers);

  return (
    <div className="to-do-app">
      <button onClick={check}>CHECK✅</button>
      <InsertPanel onAddUser={addUser} />
      <Main users={users} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Проверьте имена переменных, нет ли пересечений и перекрытий.  Так же первую выборку данных из localStorage положите в ваш useEffect.

Comment: @SwaD спасибо за ответ.
конечно, проверял переменные, возможно что-то не доглядел, конечно. но проверял методом переименования чтобы точно пересечений не было.
второе предложение не понял, не могли бы перефразировать что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Ниже дали как раз ответ по этому поводу, о переносе чтения хранилища в useEffect. Осталось понять, что такое у вас `usersObj`. Зачем его в хранлище каждый раз запихивать. Если это "начальные данные", то их лучше положить в useState, как значение по умолчанию.

Comment: @SwaD `usersObj` - отдельный массив с 4-я объектами, хранящийся в отдельном файле проекта. мне кажется так код смотрится лучше, чем всё сразу пихать в `useState` по умолчанию.

Comment: У компонента должно быть начальное состояние. И если userObj это оно и есть, то на случай отсутствия данных в localStorage я бы вообще сделал так: ` useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || userObj)` , это позволит избавиться от useEffect и как следствие, лишнего рендера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в вашем коде связана с тем, что вы используете `localUsers`, который инициализирован в **начале компонента** и затем изменяется внутри функции `addUser`. Когда вы вызываете `setUsers(localUsers)`, React не обнаруживает изменений в localUsers, так как это всегда **один и тот же объект**.

Вот как всё должно быть:

```
export default function ToDoApp() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);

  // Загрузка данных из localStorage при первом рендере
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const localUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
    if (localUsers) {
      setUsers(localUsers);
    }
  }, []);

  function addUser({ ...user }) {
    // Создать новый массив с обновленными данными
    const updatedUsers = [...users, user];

    // Обновить localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(updatedUsers));

    // Установить новый массив в состояние
    setUsers(updatedUsers);
  }

  const check = () => console.log(users);

  return (
    <div className="to-do-app">
      <button onClick={check}>CHECK✅</button>
      <InsertPanel onAddUser={addUser} />
      <Main users={users} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ и разъяснения.
однако остается вопрос почему ```console.log()``` так же логирует разные показания с ```setUsers(localUsers);``` в конце и без.
напомню, что без он при каждом добавление пользователя отображает новый массив с новым объектом. без – добавляется только один объект в массив и в последующем только он и изменяется.
и, к сожалению, ваш код не работает. ведет себя он точно так же.

Comment: А вы точно в setUsers посылаете обновленный массив? Можете код ваш предоставить, так как по идее проблема именно в том что каждый раз при обновлении массива, нужно обновлять localStorage новым массивом. Пересоздавать его

Comment: [вот скриншот](https://imageup.ru/img64/4575918/snimok-ekrana-2023-10-16-v-222133.jpg.html)
не разобрался как красиво сюда скопировать код

Comment: @sharkavli Добавьте в вопрос, нажав на кнопку "править" ниже вопроса, полный код компонента, что бы можно было увидеть, как определны переменные состояния, чтение и сохранение localStorage.

Comment: @sharkavli Понял, теперь проблему сразу увидел, обновил ответ свой)

Comment: @E1mir , спасибо, ваше решение мне помогло. Действительно добавляются новые пользователи. Если вам не трудно, подскажите следующее: в вашем решении в ```localStorage``` убирается новый массив ```updatedUsers``` с ключом ```'users'```. однако ниже в оригинальной функции ```check()``` : 
```const check = () => console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')));``` я пытаюсь просмотреть массив, хранящийся в ```localStorage``` и он выдает оригианльный мой массив, который закладывается в ```useEffect()```
почему так?

Comment: потому что в функции addUser мы обновляем localStorage и сам state, из-за этого там два одинаковых массива